# Greater than and less than values in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

I want to make a bank system where it checks whether a particular applicant has a low, medium or high account balance.

for example if a person's bank account has only 500 dollar, system will categorize him as Low and if a person has 1,000,000 dollar, the system will categorize him as High.

However, I have no idea how to put in between the values of greater than and less than value when wanted to find which applicant has the medium or highest value.

Here is the code I tried

```
app(john,10).
app(mike, 10000).
app(jasmine, 10000).
app(ayyy, 1000000).

balance_low(X) :-
    app(X, Y),
    Y < 5000.

balance_medium(X):-
    app(X, Y),
    Y >= 5000,

balance_high(X):-
    app(X, Y),
    Y > 100000.
```

How do I make the balance_medium(X) to have the condition where Y is more than equals 5000 AND less than 100000?

I'm new to prolog and I tried searching online for help but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Add `Y =< 10000`

Comment: Oh I didn't know it'll work. The first time I attempted it didn't work but now somehow it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Probably you tried `Y <= 10000` instead